# will crying increase the probability of Dua granting?

Tags: practical-islam

I want to know if there is any relation between crying and praying?(from the viewpoint of Islam)  And will the probability of prayers granting be increased by crying?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crying is psychological phenomenon which occurs naturally when we become highly emotional either happy or sad. You can't force it to happen.

You feel like crying in the following situations.

1. If you fear the punishment of afterlife and ask for forgiveness
2. If you are facing hard time and want Allah's help.
3. if you are extremely happy about some great achievement and really thank Allah from bottom of your heart.

So, when crying the communication strength between you and Allah increases by many times.

May the creator guide us all.

Comment: You mentioned some remarkable points regarding "You feel like crying in the following situations...". Yeah, those situations could be related to the crying.

Comment: Oh Allah do not call me to account for what they say & forgive me for what they have no knowledge of [and make me better than they imagine]" @السید____علی

Comment: could u illustrate wht u mean? I confirmed your word at my comment. actually I said those are true items which you mentioned, in fact I mean I agree you dear mate

Comment: check this out buddy.. can we praise other people??? http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23047/can-we-praise-other-people . @السید____علی