# Can we praise other people?

Tags: halal-haram, quran, hadith, fiqh, sunnah

Can we praise other people for their deeds like

"Nice work done", or "Hats off, you did a great job today",

or even like "You're a very good person" or "you're very intelligent"?

Any rulings which prohibit such things? I feel there's something wrong in that because we most often praise others to get some of our work done.

Comment: ur quest relatively could be considered as a common issue between many people by different aims. I assume the intention is so significant in the rightness or wrongness of the mentioned matter. (God willing, I'll answer ur inquiry today)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Know that the life of this world is but amusement and diversion and adornment and **boasting to one another** and competition in increase of wealth and children - like the example of a rain whose [resulting] plant growth pleases the tillers; then it dries and you see it turned yellow; then it becomes [scattered] debris. And in the Hereafter is severe punishment and forgiveness from Allah and approval. And what is the worldly life except the enjoyment of delusion.(Qur'an 57:20)

Volume 3, Book 48, Number 830 :
Narrated by Abu Bakra

> **A man praised another man in front of the Prophet** . The Prophet said to him, "Woe to you, you have cut off your companion's neck, you have cut off your companion's neck," repeating it several times and then added, "Whoever amongst you has to praise his brother should say, 'I think that he is so and so, and Allah knows exactly the truth, and I do not confirm anybody's good conduct before Allah, but I think him so and so,' if he really knows what he says about him."

At the first place, praising another person by the Prophet (peace be upon him) is not encountered in any hadith(as far as I've come across). So, it is highly advisable not to praise other people.

But, as did the above verse state the natural tendency of man, and neither did the above hadith forbid to praise, so, it's not forbidden. But in fact it is suggested to put on their opinion only if at all they like a person or his deed, rather than praising explicitly.

Even in terms of psychology, the person who is praised gets high and sometimes kinda feels "I'm the best" and it is bad for him.

> **Do not think those who rejoice for what they have done** and love that they should be praised for what they have not done-- so do by no means think them to be safe from the chastisement, and they shall have a painful chastisement. 3:188

That is why this **Du'a** is recommended **for those who are praised**

> This supplication was not taught to us by the Prophet (sal Allahu alayhi wa sallam), but it is one that his best friend, Abu Bakr (radi Allahu anhu) would make after being praised (some narrations state that it was a duaa of Ali radi Allahu anhu).

It is reported that he would say,

> #### O Allah, make me better than what they think of me, and forgive me for what they do not know about me, and do not take me to account for what they say about me.
>
> And to Allah belongs the dominion of the heavens and the earth, and Allah has power over all things. (Qur'an 3:189)
>
> ## So all the praises and thanks are to Allah, the Lord of the heavens and the Lord of the earth, and the Lord of the 'Aalamin (mankind, jinns and all that exists).
>
> (Qur'an 45:36)

May the creator guide us all.

<sub>**Support:** [The Supplication Series: Being Praised](http://muslimmatters.org/2011/04/26/the-supplication-series-being-praised/)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong in praising someone for achieving something good. The phrase that should actually be used is ما شاء الله (Mā shāʼ Allāh). The phrase is saying that it happened due to the will of Allah. "As God has willed".

Answer (score 1):

```
           In the name of Allah, the Entirely Merciful, the Especially Merciful
```

Initially I ought to mention that unfortunately as you said in your inquiry, perhaps majority of people praise other people with the intention of flattery (to doing their own works in case probably they'll be encounter him/her...), or to attract the attention of the second person who could … . Furthermore, on the whole, flattery is considered as negative practice. But totally it won’t be an impermissible practice to encourage or praise other people for their positive practices (by observing some points).

**Hence, in order to elucidate the issue, there are some significant points which ought to be paid attention, such as:**

- The praise ought not to be with flattery intention …
- The praise ought not to be cause to make him/her proud for his/her good deed.
- It would be appreciated if we praise encourages him/her to keep on his/her good deed.
- Occasionally perhaps it could be our duty to praise the persons who have done something for us.
- And some other points.

Comment: "It would be appreciated if we praise encourages him/her to keep on his/her good deed.".... by this anyone would feel proud and feel "I'm the best".. you cannot stop that... so it is better not to... I guess...

Comment: Dear mate, do u mean never praising some people won't encourage them to repeat their good deeds?

Comment: see you can always remind a person to do good deeds by pointing verses from Qur'an or by reminding about Paradise and hellfire, but, encouraging a person just by praising is not the only solution...

Comment: Yes, I agree u. Of course I don't mean the only solution is encouraging... In the meanwhile as u mentioned, pointing Quran verses is considered as an appropriate and effective way as well.